# In which criteria separate code into packages in an Android Application

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application using eclipse which has totally 29 classes in a package called com.companyname.appname.This 29 classes includes Activities,List Fragments,Loaders,Service, DbHelper,Jsonparser,Adapter and NetworkConnection classes.

I plan to separate packages like below,

***Method 1:***

- com.companyname.appname.activities (includes all **activity** class of application)
- com.companyname.appname.services (includes all **service** class of application)
- com.companyname.appname.loaders (includes all **loader** class of application)
- com.companyname.appname.fragments (includes all **fragment** class of application)
- com.companyname.appname.database (includes all **database** helper class of application)
- com.companyname.appname.utilities (includes other **utility classes**(Jsonparser,Netwrok connection detection,SimpleCursorAdapter) of application)

***Method 2:***

- Separate each package for each Activity(it includes the associated fragments,loaders,utilities,services,etc)

Which is the efficient method? Or I need to separate packages in different method efficiently?
What are all the best practices of package separation in android code design?

Comment: I use first one. Also i have onle more package level like `UI` wich includes all stuff related to UI : Activity,Fragments, Views, Components(Adapters) etc.

Answer (score 2):

packages purpose is just for organization. The first method will allow you without thinking too much to place new classes and find them easily.

The second method will be harder sometime, because some classes can be classified in several packages.

Answer (score 2):

To a great extent, it's a matter of taste.  As to some criteria , like with other kinds of encapsulation,  the following can be applied :

1. Loose coupling
2. Tight cohesion

In other words, avoid unnecessary dependencies among unrelated parts and group together what belongs together.

Think of your packages potentially reused in another application or another type of build: phone/tablet, Google / Amazon.  Or, contrary,  ones too specific to a particular case to be ever reused.

That or other  kind of reasoning will help you structure your code based on some needs rather than an arbitrary choice.

Edit: An anecdotal analogy.  Recommendations on arranging files into folders, AFAIK, from Microsoft once explaining their "object oriented" UX.  One way: have folders like Word Documents, Excel Spreadsheets, etc.  And the other like Business, Entertainment, etc.  Same approach applies to any packaging.